# Using sed to add line to end of .JSON file

Tags: json, sed

I have a .json file that looks something like this:

```
{
    "Direction": "down",
    "Conversion": "Complete",
    "Version": "v1.0.20170724"
}
```

I want to add a line to the end, so I did this:

```
sed -i '$s/}/,\t"Task":"Yes"}/' data.json
```

Which changes the file to this:

```
{
    "Direction": "down",
    "Conversion": "Complete",
    "Version": "v1.0.20170724"
,   "Task":"Yes"
}
```

Is there a way to have the comma be at the end of second to last line rather than on the last line?

Comment: which error do you get? Does it work fine?

Comment: I managed to fix my issue. I added the -i option to have the output be reflected in the file. Everything seems to work now. Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to have helped you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `sed` command for this purpose:

```
$ cat -vTE file.json 
{$
^I"Direction": "down",$
^I"Conversion": "Complete",$
^I"Version": "v1.0.20170724"$
}$

$ fileLength=$(wc -l file.json | cut -d' ' -f1); sed "$((fileLength-1))s/$/,/; ${fileLength}i  \\\t\"Task\":\"Yes\"" file.json                 
{
        "Direction": "down",
        "Conversion": "Complete",
        "Version": "v1.0.20170724",
        "Task":"Yes"
}
```

**Explanations:**

1. `fileLength=$(wc -l file.json | cut -d' ' -f1);` is used to determine the length of the file here `5`.
2. `$((fileLength-1))s/$/,/;` will add the comma at the end of the 4th line.
3. `${fileLength}i  \\\t\"Task\":\"Yes\"` is used to insert `"Task":"Yes"` just before last line!

You can redirect the output of the command to a new file or use `sed -i.bak` to activate inline mode and make the changes directly in the file.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/\n}/{s//,&/;P;s/".*,/"Task":"Yes"/};P;D' file
```

Read two lines at a time into the pattern space. If the second line begins with `}`, insert a `,` before the newline, print the amended first line, substitute the new values into the first line and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON file is formatted with indents
then search for the one and only `}` in the end.
Then insert a line before that.

```
sed -i '/^}/i,   "Task":"Yes"' data.json
```

Eventually run a JSON lint afterwards:

```
python -mjson.tool data.json
```